# How to filter Design from CustomerCode in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have created a table called `tblTread` with the following columns and sample data:

```
   TreadId  TreadSize   Design  SupplierCode    SupplierName
   ----------------------------------------------------------
    3025    150          R        SU01            ALEX
    3026    150          L        SU01            ALEX
    3027    150          R        SU02            SANDANUWAN
    3028    150          L        SU02            SANDANUWAN
```

Now I want to filter `TreadSize` and `Design` by `SupplierCode`. I tried to do it but I got following output.

```
SELECT Design
FROM tblTread
WHERE TreadSize = '150'
```

Output:

```
       Design
         R
         L
         R
         L
```

But here I want to get only `Design` related to the `SupplierCode`, like this

```
    Design
      R
      L
```

Comment: *I want to get only Design related to the SupplierCode* - so *which* supplierCode?

Comment: Perhaps ... Select distinct Design from tblTread where TreadSize =  '150'  and SupplierCode = 'SU01'

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are reading this result set:

| Design |
| --- |
| R |
| L |
| R |
| L |

and you are expecting, because the same value is repeated, that SQL Server ought to consolidate those results on the basis of it not showing you why the records differ.

The query engine does not, and can not, reduce or consolidate the number of rows returned unless it is instructed to do so, regardless of the number of columns returned, their values, or the order in which they are presented.

In order to consolidate your results, you must provide the query engine instructions for how to perform that consolidation. @John Cappelletti's comment illustrates three ways of doing this: Add the `DISTINCT` keyword to eliminate redundant values in the columns selected for return; provide additional `WHERE` predicates to constrain the results to particular conditions (such as SupplierCode); or do both of these things.

The third of these options is likely to be the most correct, based on the logical requirements you state as "I want to get only `Design` related to the `SupplierCode`". That approach, `DISTINCT` with a `WHERE` predicate on SupplierCode, will eliminate rows for other suppliers from the result set and will also remove redundant rows based on the values of columns specified in the `SELECT`